# Moving Records based on Type, Confirmation Date, Type Table Hours Offset and working Calendar Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time

I have been attempting to automate my Order movement process in SQL Server 2014 by having it look for these criteria;

- Order Type (Green, Blue, Purple)
- Confirmation Date (FIRST Date that a confirmation is sent to a customer)
- Order Type Table Hours Offset (Green Orders = 48, Blue Orders = 24, Purple Orders = 0)
- Office Calendar Date (Working Day = 1, non-working day = 0)

I have been able to get normal working days functioning great. Problem lies when

- Confirmation Date + Order Type Table Offset = a non-working day (0)
- Confirmation (Confirmation Date) was sent on a non-working day (0)

Those days get ignored and I have wrote a small program that determines which are "overdue" and have someone manually moving them. The end goal is to have the entire process automated rather having manual intervention.

Here is the program that functions for working days

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT oc.ocDate
              FROM dbo.OfficeCalendar oc
              WHERE oc.ocID = 1
                  AND CONVERT(DATE,oc.ocDate) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))
    BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #OfficeDays (id INT IDENTITY
                              ,offDate DATETIME
                              ,offIN INT NULL)
    INSERT INTO #OfficeDays 
    SELECT TOP 14 oc.ocDate
                  ,oc.ocIN
    FROM dbo.OfficeCalendar oc
    WHERE oc.ocID = 1
       AND oc.ocDate <= GETDATE()
    ORDER BY oc.ocDate DESC
    
    --UPDATE odr
    --SET odr.status = 3 -- Move order to Locked
    
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT odr.OrderID
                          ,DATEADD(HOUR,oto.otoHoursOffset,aa.[Conf Date]) AS [Conf Date + Offset]
                          ,ot.typeCode
          FROM dbo.Orders odr
          JOIN dbo.Types AS ot ON ot.otID = odr.otID
          JOIN dbo.OfficeTableOffset AS oto ON oto.otoOrderType = ot.otCode
          JOIN dbo.OrderStatus AS os ON os.osID = odr.osID
          --
          OUTER APPLY(SELECT MIN(h.odrChangeDate) AS [Conf Date]
                      FROM dbo.OrderHistoryLog AS h
                      JOIN dbo.OrderStatus AS os ON os.osID = h.osID
                      WHERE h.odrID = odr.odrID
                      AND h.osID = 2) aa
          --
          WHERE odr.osID = 2) AS result
    JOIN dbo.Orders AS odr1 ON odr1.odrID = CONVERT(DATETIME,result.odrID,120)
    JOIN dbo.Types AS ot1 ON ot1.otID = odr1.otID
    JOIN dbo.OfficeTableOffset AS oto1 ON oto1.otoOrderType = ot1.otCode
    JOIN #OfficeDays AS ocd ON ocd.offDate = CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(result.[Conf Date + Offset],11))
    --
    **OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(SUM(oc.ocIN)*24,0) AS [OfficeHours]
                FROM #OfficeDays oc
                WHERE oc.ocDate BETWEEN result.[Conf Date] AND CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(GETDATE(),11))) bb**
    --
    WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(result.[Conf Date + Offset],11)) < = CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(ocd.offDate,11))
             AND DATEPART(hh,result.[Conf Date + Offset]) < DATEPART(hh,GETDATE())
             **AND bb.[OfficeHours] > = oto.otoHoursOffset**
DROP #OfficeDays
END
```

Here is the OfficeTableOffset Table

```
ID otoOrderType  otoHoursOffset
1  Green         48
2  Blue          24
3  Purple        0
```

Here is the OfficeCalendar Table

```
id  ocID  ocDate      ocIN
1   1     2023-12-20  1
2   1     2023-12-21  1
3   1     2023-12-22  1
4   1     2023-12-23  0
5   1     2023-12-24  0
6   1     2023-12-25  0
7   1     2023-12-26  0
8   1     2023-12-27  1
9   1     2023-12-28  1
10  1     2023-12-29  1
11  1     2023-12-30  0
```

So the main problems are;

- If a "Green" Order (+48hrs) gets confirmed (2) on 21st (48hrs = 22nd and 27th)
- If a "Green Order (+48hrs) gets confirmed (2) on the 23rd (48hrs = 27th, 28th)
- If a "Blue" Order (+24hrs) gets confirmed (2) on the 22nd (24hrs = 27th)
- If a "Blue" Order (+24hrs) get confirmed (2) on the 23rd (24hrs = 27th)

During the week, it runs great, orders that are not included as "Office Working Days" within the Calendar, it ignores and we have to manually update them.

```
OrderNumber Confirmation Date Lock Date        Confirmation Hour Type  Offset Hours Actual Lock Date
4641        2023-12-19 05:56  2023-12-21 05:56 5                 Green 48           2023-12-21
5019        2023-12-21 11:55  2023-12-23 11:55 11                Green 48           2023-12-27
```

*Actual Lock Date is based on whether the +48/24 lands on a day where the Office is not scheduled (0) based on the OfficeCalendar table.
**Actual Lock Date counts day scheduled (1) as 24hrs

I have been working on this problem since the middle of November and at the end on how to resolve this.

Any input would be appreciated.

Regards,
Gary

Comment: Hey Gary, can you explain this bit a little more: 'If a "Green" Order (+48hrs) gets confirmed (2) on 21st (48hrs = 22nd and 27th)' ? Not following how it could be 22nd and/or 27th? Are there time thresholds? I understand how it could be the 27th, because 21 + 48 hours is the 23rd (Saturday), then the 25th is Christmas and you probably give people the 26th off too. So that's 27th. But not clear on how it could also be the 22nd?

Comment: If you can provide sample data in tables (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow) with your input sample and expected result, with as many edge cases as you can think of. That would really help folks. If I'm understanding this, I've seen people run in to similar problems in the Finance world. Where there is latency in data flows by system they have to have a custom map between the source's process date and the actual ledger date. They solved it by adding a custom "Next Business Day" to the calendar by system offset.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to move orders only when the confimration hits on a week day, or just after a holiday in case it's a holiday? so you want to wait until they are, and then move them? Or what? You write the how, but not the what and why

Comment: @Error_2646, 22nd would be a Friday, and a valid, in Office Date. No one is scheduled to be in the office until the 27th which, is the next business day. Hence the gap between the proposed 48 hour calculation.

As for table samples, I did provide two above. These are the main two I am bouncing the data off in order to get the intended result.

I can supply some output (adding in a SELECT statement + fields) if you want to see output on how the program works.

Comment: @GaryAMacDonald I know it'd be tedious, but providing actual data or a minimum simplified representation of actual data would help a great deal. Along with the expected result from that sample. Reproducibility is the name of the game.

Comment: Let me work on it then.. stay tuned.

Comment: OrderNumber Confirmation Date Lock Date              Confirmation Hour Type    Offset Hours
4641                2023-12-19 05:56  2023-12-21 05:56  5                             Green  48
5019                2023-12-21 11:55  2023-12-23 11:55  11                           Green  48

Order 5019 has a lock date of 12-23 which of course is a Saturday, and non-office hour according to the sample table I provided in my original inquiry.

This should be the 27th of December.

Comment: @Error_2646, formatting responses are a pain. I have updated my main question to include a sample table to show what I am trying to achieve. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @GaryAMacDonald ChatGPT is what it is. But, for what it's worth, it's actually a pretty dynamite test data generator. If you describe the structure and constraints of the tables you can usually corral it into a good data set. Then ask it to format it as StackOverflow markdown.

Comment: **Resolved**
Please see original code for details of additions. This will now count proper days and compare to current.